# How to configure mod_cluster with JBoss EAP 6 while it is running in domain mode?

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, mod-cluster

If application server instances reside on different machines ? 
I mainly want to know the configurations guide on the jboss eap server side.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this how-to a while ago on our project wiki: [JBoss AS instances in Domain mode with mod_cluster load balancer](https://github.com/modcluster/mod_cluster/wiki/FAQ#q-jboss-as-instances-in-domain-mode-with-mod_cluster-load-balancer). Please, check it out and ask away if it didn't help.